# SCNView contents are not appearing correctly

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am trying to get a simple SceneKit demo working (it's a Ray Wenderlich tutorial). I am setting the the contents of the SCNView:

```
func setupScene() {
    scnScene = SCNScene()
    scnScene.background.contents = UIImage(named: "GeometryFighter.scnassets/Textures/Background_Diffuse.png")
    scnView.scene = scnScene
        }
```

In the storyboard I have set the View's alpha to 1 and the background to default.

However, the image should be a gradient fill in mid blue. What comes out is a gradient in black and grey. If I change the alpha down from 1 in the storyboard it just gets darker until it is black.

I don't understand why it is not just displaying the picture?

Any help gratefully received.

Comment: I tested your code and it works. Are you changing any of the properties of the scene?

Comment: Not that I know - I tried a new project with the code from the view controller cut and paste into a new game template. I got the same result. I think I don't understand the layering of the views and images as the scene is displayed. I'll do some more research.

Comment: I suggest that you test with another image. Also, did you check if the UIImage call is returning non nil value?

Comment: UIImage is non-nil - I can see the image itself, but it is a faded black and grey version of the correct image as if it is filtered through another layer. I will check a different, very distinct image.

Comment: So I got it to work by resizing the original image up from 512x512 to 2048x2048. The Content Mode is Aspect Fill. Was the original simply spread too thin? I have a working solution, but I don't want to answer the question when I am not sure I understand what happened.

Comment: I found this from Apple, "Because the texture atlas is still a texture, it is subject to the OpenGL ES implementation’s maximum texture size as well as other texture attributes." I believe the OpenGL texture size limit is 2048x2048.